# Is the implementation of the blkio subsystem in cgroups complete?

Tags: linux-kernel, cgroups

I am trying to set upper limits on processes. The read access is correctly bounded. However, the behavior for write operations is wrong.

I am dealing with pseudo-files read_bps_device and write_bps_device.

In http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt, last paragraph, I read the text below. Nevertheless, it is not clear for me if they are talking about CFQ or also about Throttling.

## What works?

- Currently only sync IO queues are support. All the buffered writes are
  still system wide and not per group. Hence we will not see service
  differentiation between buffered writes between groups.